# Docker gitlab container will be unhealthy and can't be accessed by url after 48 hours

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ce

```
export GITLAB_HOME=/srv/gitlab
sudo docker run --detach \
--hostname 172.xx.xx.xx \
--publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 \
--name gitlab_formal \
--restart=on-failure:3 \
--volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab \
--volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
--volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
--shm-size 4g \
gitlab/gitlab-ce:15.1.1-ce.0
```

I tried above command to establish the docker gitlab container successfully.
After the docker gitlab container's running time changed from "xx hours ago" to "xx days ago", it's state will be 'unhealthy', and it will not be able to access via url address.

I have check the setting of the timezone, while it doesn't work. The phenomenon still exists.